# iterrows producing extra unwanted output from dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

In the code below I'm trying to get the 'proid' value and 'uim' value for each row of a dataframe.  I'm trying to parse the first and second values from the 'proid' value and use them to create a new directory for each record.  So for example for the first record it would create the directory '/stuff/_place/1/2' for the second record it would be '/stuff/_place/2/2'.  The problem I'm running in to is that it's just creating directories 1 through 9, that's '/stuff/_place/1' to ''/stuff/_place/9', even though many of those numbers aren't present in the records in the dataframe.  Does anyone see what the issue is and how I can accomplish my original goal?

The code worked correctly when I tested it for just the first record in the dataframe using .iloc[0] like the commented out code below.  It started producing the extra directories when I tried using iterrows like the example below.

[How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

```
Code:

# iterows through whole data frame
sampleDf=testDf

for index, row in sampleDf.iterrows():


    pid=row['proid'] #sampleDf['proid'].iloc[0]

    ImgUrl=row['uim'] #sampleDf['uim'].iloc[0]


    # file path where images stored
    basePath=‘/stuff/_place/‘

    # 1st digit
    dig1=str(pid)[0]

    # 2nd digit
    dig2=str(pid)[1]

    # checking if directory exists and making new directory if it doesn't
    directory=basePath+dig1+'/'+dig2

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)


Data:

proid   uim
123 red
224 veg
456 fog
```

Comment: What is the logic to split a 3 digit number to dig1 and dig2 ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? I had to edit the code so that it runs, and it works without a problem. Next time, write the code so that it is possible to copy and past it and then run it without needing to change anything.

The following code, adapted from yours

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# iterows through whole data frame
sampleDf= pd.DataFrame([[123, 'red'], [224, 'veg'], [456, 'fog']],columns=['proid', 'uim'])

for index, row in sampleDf.iterrows():


    pid=row['proid'] #sampleDf['proid'].iloc[0]

    ImgUrl=row['uim'] #sampleDf['uim'].iloc[0]


    # file path where images stored
    basePath="/stuff/_place/"

    # 1st digit
    dig1=str(pid)[0]

    # 2nd digit
    dig2=str(pid)[1]

    # checking if directory exists and making new directory if it doesn't
    directory=basePath+dig1+'/'+dig2

    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
```

Creates the following directories:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems to have been a hick up with my notebook.  I think the test dataframe I was using got confused with an earlier dataframe and so was using the whole index from the earlier dataframe instead of the just a few records.